# Best way to do API shadowing on GCP

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, microservices

We are trying to transition from one microservice to another implementation. In order to properly test it in production, we are looking into shadowing the request in production to new service, and then comparing the result and logging any discrepancy. I am looking for the best tool than can do it out of the box. Previously we managed to do it with nginx, but I prefer an out of the box solution like Google cloud endpoints, or Apigee.

Comment: Google does not have an "out of the box" solution like AWS API Gateway (yet). Cloud Endpoints and Apigee have signification learning curves. If you have a solution with Nginx, I would stay with that. Otherwise, I recommend investing in learning Apigee.

Comment: Does Apigee has a solution for this ?

Comment: Apigee is a framework/service. As I mentioned there is no "out of the box" solution. Apigee can do almost anything with APIs.